# Конвертация XPS в PDF C#

Tags: c#, конвертация

Пытаюсь сконвертировать XPS в PDF. Для этого скачал через NuGet библиотеку XpsToPdf.

```
<PackageReference Include="XpsToPdf" Version="1.0.5" />
```

В ней есть класс XpsConverter.
Вот мой код:

```
var _xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(stream, FileAccess.Read);
// Создаем экземпляр PdfDocument
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
// Используем XpsConverter для конвертации XPS в PDF
XpsConverter.Convert(_xpsDocument, pdfDocument, 0);
// Подготавливаем поток для записи PDF
var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
pdfDocument.Save(pdfStream);
pdfStream.Position = 0;
// Устанавливаем заголовки ответа для PDF
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
var encodedFileName = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileData.name);
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"{System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(encodedFileName, ".pdf")}\"");

// Возвращаем FileStreamResult с PDF
return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
```

После компиляции возникает ошибка:

```
/mnt/d/Users/Lev/adcm/18/ADCM_Connect/PilotWebApplication/PilotWebApplication.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.Windows. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

Из ошибки понятно что нет библиотеки которая реализует класс  XpsDocument  находил что такой класс есть в System.Windows.Xps.Packaging но через NuGet этот пакет не устанавливается. подскажите что я делаю не так?

Вот мои текущие зависимости:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Ascon.Pilot.Common" Version="20.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ascon.Pilot.DataClasses" Version="20.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ascon.Pilot.DataModifier" Version="20.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ascon.Pilot.SDK" Version="23.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ascon.Pilot.Server.Api" Version="23.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ascon.Pilot.Transport" Version="20.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="GhostscriptSharp" Version="1.3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="PdfSharp" Version="1.50.5147" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Pdf.Net.Core" Version="17.3.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.XpsToPdfConverter.Net.Core" Version="17.3.0.14" /> 
    <!-- <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Claims" Version="4.3.0" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="XpsToPdf" Version="1.0.5" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="System.Windows" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно устанавливать `System.Windows`, его нет в NuGet, так как он является частью .NET, вместо этого смените целевую платформу и пересоберите проект.

```xml
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

При этом проект перестанет быть кроссплатформенным, и его невозможно будет собрать для запуска на платформах, отличных от Windows.

Comment: После перехода net6.0-windows и долгих мучений код заработал. 
Но теперь для некоторых файлов возникает ошибка:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN290HLBBG87", Request id "0HN290HLBBG87:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.ArgumentException: StaticResource not found: {StaticResource R0}

Comment: @ЛевГерасимов если у вас появился новый вопрос, лучше задать его отдельно.